# Haar measure for isomorphic groups

Tags: measure-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be topological isomorphic groups. Let $\Phi:G\rightarrow H$ be the corresponding group isomorphism. Suppose $\mu$ is a Haar measure on $\mathcal{B}(G)$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on G, will $\mu\left(\Phi^{-1}\left(\cdot\right)\right)$ be a Haar measure on $H$?

I am relatively new to Haar measure and related topics. Can anyone help me proving this?

Comment: Is this a trick question? Are the groups also homeomorphic to each other?

Comment: @MattSamuel: Yes, they are also homeomorphic to each other according to this definition from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group. No, it's not meant to be a trick question.

Comment: If $\Phi$ is a isomorphism of topological groups, i.e. a group isomorphisms which is also a homeomorphism, then this should work.

Comment: Well if the Haar measure depends only on the topological group structure, then this should be straightforward verification. To be honest I don't remember the definition.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner: How do I formally prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with Haar measures, so I will check that $\nu \colon \mathcal{B}(H) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\nu(A) = \mu(\Phi^{-1}(A))$ satisfies the properties of a (left) Haar measure as [defined by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#Haar.27s_theorem). I assume that $\Phi \colon G \to H$ is an isomorphism of topological groups, i.e. an isomorphism of groups which is also a homeomorphism.

---

First we notice that because $\Phi$ is continuous it it follows that $\Phi \colon (G, \mathcal{B}(G)) \to (H,\mathcal{B}(H))$ is measurable. In the same way we find that $\Phi^{-1} \colon (H, \mathcal{B}(H)) \to (G,\mathcal{B}(G))$ is measurable (here we use that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism). So a subset $A \subseteq H$ is Borel-measurable if and only if $\Phi^{-1}(A)$ is Borel-measurable. In particular $\nu$ is well-defined.

---

$\nu$ defines a measure on $(H,\mathcal{B}(H))$: For every $A \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ we have $\nu(A) = \mu(\Phi^{-1}(A)) \geq 0$, and we also have $\nu(\emptyset) = \mu(\Phi^{-1}(\emptyset)) = \mu(\emptyset) = 0$. Given a countable collection $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of Borel-measurable subsets $A_n \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ which are pairwise disjoint, i.e. $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$, the preimages $\Phi^{-1}(A_n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are also Borel-measurable and pairwise disjoint, so
\begin{align*}
 \nu\left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \right)
 &= \mu\left(\Phi^{-1}\left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \right)\right)
 = \mu\left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \Phi^{-1}(A_n) \right) \\
 &= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(\Phi^{-1}(A_n))
 = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \nu(A_n).
\end{align*}
Alltogether this shows that $\nu$ is a measure on $(H,\mathcal{B}(H))$.

---

Because $\nu(H) = \mu(\Phi^{-1}(H)) = \mu(G)$ it follows from $\mu$ not being trivial that $\nu$ is not trivial. If $A \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ and $h \in H$ then
$$
 \nu(hA)
 = \mu(\Phi^{-1}(hA))
 = \mu(\Phi^{-1}(h) \Phi^{-1}(A))
 = \mu(\Phi^{-1}(A))
 = \nu(A),
$$
so from the left-invariance of $\mu$ it follows that $\nu$ is left invariant (here we have used that $\Phi^{-1}$ is a group isomorphism).

If $K \subseteq H$ is compact then so is $\Phi^{-1}(K)$, because $\Phi^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism, and therefore $\nu(K) = \mu(\Phi^{-1}(K)) < \infty$.

All that’s left is to show that $\nu$ is outer regular and inner regular. Let $A \in \mathcal{B}(H)$. Because $\Phi^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}(G)$ and $\mu$ is outer regular and $\Phi^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism we have
\begin{align*}
 \nu(A)
 &= \mu(\Phi^{-1}(A)) \\
 &= \inf \{\mu(U) \mid \text{$U \subseteq G$ is open with $\Phi^{-1}(A) \subseteq U$}\} \\
 &= \inf \{\mu(\Phi^{-1}(V)) \mid \text{$V \subseteq H$ is open with $\Phi^{-1}(A) \subseteq \Phi^{-1}(V)$}\} \\
 &= \inf \{\nu(V) \mid \text{$V \subseteq H$ is open with $A \subseteq V$}\}.
\end{align*}
So $\nu$ is outer regular. Similarly we have
\begin{align*}
 \nu(A)
 &= \mu(\Phi^{-1}(A)) \\
 &= \sup \{\mu(K) \mid \text{$K \subseteq G$ is compact with $K \subseteq \Phi^{-1}(A)$}\} \\
 &= \sup \{\mu(\Phi^{-1}(K')) \mid \text{$K' \subseteq H$ is compact with $\Phi^{-1}(K') \subseteq \Phi^{-1}(A)$}\} \\
 &= \sup \{\nu(K') \mid \text{$K' \subseteq H$ is compact with $K' \subseteq A$}\},
\end{align*}
so $\nu$ is also inner regular.

Altogether this shows that $\nu$ is a Haar measure on $(H,\mathcal{B}(H))$.

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I'm looking for.